# emacs helm-git-grep is super slow on windows, alternative?

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-helm

I can use whatever version of emacs on windows, just want to use helm-git-grep or similar alternatives on windows.

Anyone using emacs on windows has a tip for git-grep functionality?

Comment: If you're happy to jump through a big-ish hoop, I can recommend hosting a Linux VM on your Windows box (n.b. definitely most efficient to run the guest without a desktop environment; Ubuntu Server is an easy option), and running Emacs inside that (using a local X display, such as that provided by Cygwin). It might seem a little extreme, but it resolves pretty much all issues caused by using Windows :)

Comment: Is git grep fast via the command line? Try it. If it's also slow there then it's an issue with windows, not with emacs or helm.

Comment: according to the discussion on the bottom of this page http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/modernization_emacs_grep_inconsistency.html, the design of helm-git-grep is inevitably slow on windows. (forking process on each keystrokes)

Comment: @phils: thanks for the input, we took it even further, and switched to linux + terminal from windows + emacs within terminal.

Comment: Nice one. Your previous comment+link also sounds fairly definitive as far as the original question goes, so you should probably post that as a proper answer?

Comment: @phils: actually we gave up on windows terminal (couldn't find a good color theme which looks decent) and installed virtual machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative that I could suggest is [helm-rg](https://github.com/cosmicexplorer/helm-rg) that uses ripgrep—it is very fast.

You can set `helm-rg-default-directory` to `git-root` (and you need this small [tweak](https://github.com/cosmicexplorer/helm-rg/issues/10#issuecomment-636401523) on Windows). Together with [helm-projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile), it works great.